# Как задать заголовок Content-Length в Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fileupload

Пытаюсь разобраться с этой документацией.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Я бы не хотел лезть в корни node.js т.к. в данный момент специализируюсь на front-end, поэтому использую express.js т.к. он прост в освоении.
Хочу по кусочкам отослать на клиент audio/mpeg файл. 
Как инициирующий реквест с клиента, отдать Content-Length, не отдавая сам файл целиком. 
Когда просто отправляешь файлы методами 
res.sendFile
res.download
То Express.js автоматически выставляет Content-Length.
Но мне не нужно отправлять весь файл.

Буду рад ответам или ссылкам на полезные статьи (en, ru) на тему частичной передачи данных в node.js / express.js.

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос в том, как задать заголовок для ответа, то вот, примерно как то так

```
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Length': N
}); // N - длина ответа в байтах
```

Если вопрос про то, как отправить часть файла, то тут вам поможет официальная документация по [FileSystem](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/fs.html) от Node JS